# How to put the output from a ajax response in a modal iframe in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a codeigniter project. In my view I have a modal. On click at a button the modal launched and the function above is called. It do a ajax call to create a html-page and output it as response for the call. That works. Now I need to take this response and show it into the iframe. My tries failed. **What did I do wrong or in which way I have to do it?**

Background: I want to make a preview with html code which combine the static code from the view file with two given fields by the ajax call. The pages has own CSS styles. So I need to use an iframe to prepare that there are no other css-styles in conflict. **Maybe there is a easier way to do it?**

The Modal:




Compose
×

```
                <div class="row" id="preview_area">
                    <iframe id="preview_frame" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" src=""></iframe>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

The function:

```
$('#launchbutton_modal_preview').on('click',function(e){
      
       event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?= site_url(); ?>myurl/my_view/",
            data: {
                <?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?> : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>',
                head : $('input[name=subject]').val(),
                content : $('.textarea').val(),
            },          
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                    if(response != ''){
                        alert("response",response);
                        getIframeDocument($('#preview_frame')).body.update(response);
                        var iFrame = $('<iframe id="thepage"></iframe>');                            
                        var iFrameDoc = iFrame[0].response || iFrame[0].contentWindow.document;
                        iFrameDoc.write('<p>Some useful html</p>');
                        iFrameDoc.close();
                        $('#preview_area').html(iFrame);
                        
                    }
                }
        }); 
        
    });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some hours more of testing i find the quiet easy way to do what i want to do.

```
  //Add iframe with the responsepage to modal
$('<iframe id="preview_frame" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 p-0" style="position:relative;top:0px;width:100%;height:75vh;border: 1px solid #e9ecef;" src=""></iframe>')
   .appendTo('#preview_area')
   .on('load', function(){
        $(this).contents().find('body').append(response);   
});
```